# jQuery Tabs - Go direct to specific tab from URL

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using a jQuery tabs implementation and everything works great, however I want to be able to link to a URL for example http://www.mydomain.com/tabs.html#tab2 and have the page automatically open on tab 2, heres where I am at so far http://jsfiddle.net/Jmx7k/

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tabs2 li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
    jQuery('.container:not(:first)').hide();

    jQuery('#tabs2 li a').click(function() {
        var t = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive')) { //added to not animate when active
            jQuery('#tabs2 li a').addClass('inactive');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive');
            jQuery('.container').hide();
            jQuery(t).fadeIn('slow');
         }
    return false;
}) //end click
});​
</script>
    <div id="tabs2holder">
        <ul id="tabs2">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Test Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Test Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container" id="tab1">
    This is test content for tab1
</div>


<div class="container" id="tab2">
     This is test content for tab2
</div>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction of adding this functionality and also explain why it doesn't currently do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Maybe you could use this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, if you want to create an url with hash-part (e.g. '#tab2') you can get this value with

```
var hash = location.hash; // hash = '#tab2'
```

change your code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tabs2 li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
    jQuery('.container:not(:first)').hide();

    jQuery('#tabs2 li a').click(function() {
        var t = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive')) { //added to not animate when active
            jQuery('#tabs2 li a').addClass('inactive');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive');
            jQuery('.container').hide();
            jQuery(t).fadeIn('slow');
        }
        return false;
    }); //end click

    if (location.hash == '#tab2') {
        // don't forget to put id-attributes to your li-elements
        jQuery('#tablink2 a').trigger('click');
    }
});​
```

see also here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jmx7k/8/
by jsfiddle the hash-attribute is not affecting the javascript-area :-( try it in normal context.