# How to link the tabs content from another page

Tags: jquery, html

In index page I am able to see when I clicked on tab two that respected content will showing so same like when clicked in category page header tab two it has to open the index page and show to the respected tab content.

Thanks a lot if any one can tell for my solution.

[Index page](http://www.creativecorp.in/tab/index.html)
[Category page](http://www.creativecorp.in/tab/category.html)

Comment: You can go for an iframe and change its source based on the different tab clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You have tow solutions:

- Make one of the pages child of another due to make it accessible form
  the parent to child, you could do it by `window.open`  example:

If you want to access `$('#cat_id').html('text');` on category page, you can call it from index page by `window.opener.$('#cat_id').html('text2');` .

- Make shared XML file and  `setInterval` for JS function to check any
  change on the XML file

Comment: can you able to show in fiddle with modified code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5aJL/

Answer (score 0):

you have to build a hash logic like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924718/jquery-tabs-go-direct-to-specific-tab-from-url/13929851#13929851)

and then you can link like /category.html#tab3

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you wanted to make a website where clicking buttons in the nav would dynamically load some content. Kind of like the organic tabs thing, only the content is loaded dynamically. Say HTML is something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery JavaScript**

The JavaScript is the fun part here! This is the plan in plain English:

- When a navigation button is clicked...
- Change the hash tag of the URL
- When the hash tag in the URL changes...
- Fade out the old content
- Load and fade in the new content
- Update the current navigation highlighting

So why bother with the "hash tag" changing stuff? Several reasons:

By using the [hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) by Ben Alman, we can enable the browsers back/forward button. Super modern browsers support the hashchange event by themselves, this plugin enables support for it for older browsers.
We can look for the hash when the page loads and load the appropriate page (i.e. "deep linking")

**Prereq**

We'll be using the jQuery library, the onhashchange plugin, and then loading our own script last.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
```

**Code Dump**

```
$(function() {

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent.find("#guts").fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href='" + newHash + "']").addClass("current");
                });
            });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a simple hash code logic you can see here a live demo i've created before sometime http://wbs.walkover.in/branding.php#custom
or you can try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(window.location.hash){changeProduct();}
   $(window).bind('hashchange',function(){changeProduct();});
});

function changeProduct(){
    var val = window.location.hash.substring(1)

    switch(val)
        {
        case 'custom':
            $('.accclk').removeClass('active');
            $("#cst").addClass('active')
            $('.dnon').hide();
            $("#custom").show();
        break;
        case 'online':
            $('.accclk').removeClass('active');
            $("#oln").addClass('active')
            $('.dnon').hide();
            $("#online").show();
        break;
        case 'product':
            $('.accclk').removeClass('active');
            $("#prd").addClass('active')
            $('.dnon').hide();
            $("#product").show();
        break;
        case 'solution':
            $('.accclk').removeClass('active');
            $("#sol").addClass('active')
            $('.dnon').hide();
            $("#solution").show();
        break;
        }

}
```